# Printing the all possible substrings of a string sorted by length

Tags: java, string, for-loop, substring

The task requires that given a string, it should print out all possible substrings sorted by their lengths. 
For example, if the input is funny it should print

```
funny
funn
unny
fun 
unn 
nny
...
f
u
n
n
y
```

This is my code

```
public static void main( String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

    // constants

    // variables
    String input;


    // program code
    input = scan.nextLine();
    for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ )
    {
      for ( int j = i + 1 ;  j <= input.length(); j++ )
      {
        System.out.println( input.substring( i , j  ) ); 
      }
    }
  }
```

The program prints out all possible substrings but not sorted by length. I could not find a way to sort the substrings. I can only use 'do while' or 'for' loops and no arrays unfortunately.

I am relatively new to programming so I would really appreciate if you could explain your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to print the substrings in length order

For this example the test string will be `abc`.

First print with length of 3

```
abc
---  abc (0,3)
```

Then print sections with length of 2:

```
abc
--   ab  (0,2)
 --  bc  (1,3)
```

Finally, print with a section length of 1, so print:

```
abc
-    a   (0,1)
 -   b   (1,2)
  -  c   (2,3)
```

This way the strings are printed in length order

## How to implement

In pseudocode, this would be:

```
FOR length in size..1
  FOR start in 0..(size-length)
    print(substring(start, start+length)
```

In Java, this would be:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        for (int length = input.length(); length > 0; length--) {
            for (int start = 0; start <= (input.length()-length); start++) {
                System.out.println(input.substring(start, start+length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its from longest to shortest, but your concept persists.

Comment: Fixed, I overlooked that in the question

Comment: I understand the logic but how can in code this  ? :/

Comment: No problem, hope it made sense

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use variables for length and start index instead of start and end index.

```
String input = "funny";
for (int length = input.length(); length > 0; --length)
    for (int start = 0; start + length <= input.length(); ++start)
        System.out.println(input.substring(start, start + length));
System.out.println("");
```

If we would write `length >= 0` then the empty string `""` would be printed `input.length()` times. But since the empty string `""` is a substring of every string we cheat and print it only once by hand.

Comment: thanks a lot.. its frustrating to miss out on such basic ideas

Comment: @AtaAtasoy Glad I could help. Please accept the answer that helped you the most to mark your question as closed.